# Expression does not produce a value in vb.net application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, mvvm

I have a Winforms application, in which I'd like to use the MVVM design pattern :

I follow this [tutorial](http://blog.soat.fr/2012/02/comment-utiliser-mvvm-avec-windows-forms/)

It is very interesting  article, but i get this problem : My application is vb.net and I convert the code ( C#) to vb.net, it works fine except this one:

**C# code**

```
 protected void ViewModel_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.AttachedControls.ToList().ForEach(c => this.errorProvider.SetError(c.Value as Control, ""));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ViewModel.Error)) {
            this.ViewModel.Messages.ToList().ForEach(message => {
                this.errorProvider.SetError(this.ViewModel.AttachedControls[message.Key] as Control, message.Value);
            });
        }
    }
```

**Vb.net code**

```
 Protected Sub ViewModel_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Me.ViewModel.AttachedControls.ToList().ForEach(Function(c) Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(c.Value, Control), ""))
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.ViewModel.[Error]) Then
            Me.ViewModel.Messages.ToList().ForEach(Function(message)
                                                       Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(Me.ViewModel.AttachedControls(message.Key), Control), message.Value)

                                                   End Function)
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is in this line:

```
Me.ViewModel.AttachedControls.ToList().ForEach(Function(c) Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(c.Value, Control), ""))
```

**The Error:**

`Expression does not produce a value.`

I need to know

- What is the reason of this error?
- How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `Function` to `Sub`.
`Function` mean method which return value, but your code: `Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(c.Value, Control), "")` does not.

From MSDN:

> To return a value to the calling code, use a Function procedure;
>   otherwise, use a Sub procedure.

So try:

```
Me.ViewModel.AttachedControls.ToList().ForEach(Sub(c) Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(c.Value, Control), ""))
```

And also next line you need to change:

```
Me.ViewModel.Messages.ToList().ForEach(Sub(message)
                                           Me.errorProvider.SetError(TryCast(Me.ViewModel.AttachedControls(message.Key), Control), message.Value)
                                       End Sub)
```

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net **A sub and a function are both subroutines**, or sections of code that can be called in the program. The difference between them is that a function has a return value and a sub does not.
so it is better to change the function as sub to avoid the problem